# AWS Machine Learning - Django Template

Tags: python, json, django, amazon-web-services, django-templates

I have this response (I'm just showing some of response) from AWS Machine Learning:

```
{u'Prediction': {u'predictedLabel': u'Luxemburgo', u'predictedScores': {u'Irlanda': 0.0003484287590254098, u'B\xe9lgica': 0.013423046097159386, u'Espa\xf1a': 0.002083213534206152, u'Grecia': 0.0014155727112665772, u'San Marino': 0.00233459216542542, u'Letonia': 0.0008684576023370028, u'Azerbaiy\xe1n': 0.0651199221611023, u'Finlandia': 0.0015709727304056287, u'Andorra': 0.00023321053595282137, u'Italia': 0.0007921983487904072, u'Vaticano': 0.011585880070924759, u'M\xf3naco': 0.01911487616598606, u'Dinamarca': 0.004232937004417181, u'Pa\xedses Bajos': 0.0007871986017562449, u'Islandia': 0.006683974526822567, u'Francia': 0.004822706338018179, u'Montenegro': 0.018228678032755852, u'Bielorrusia': 0.0024703771341592073, u'Alemania': ...
```

I want to show users the predictedScores in a django template so I'm doing

```
{% for p in response.Prediction.predictedScores %}
    {{p}}
{% endfor %}
```

This gives me a nice list of countries BUT I also want to show the probabilities and I cannot work out how to access them.  I am sure it is simple but I cannot see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`predictedScores` is a dictionary: to iterate over a dict's keys and values, you use `items()`.

```
{% for score_name, score_value in response.Prediction.predictedScores.items %}
    {{ score_name }}: {{ score_value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you - I knew I was being dumb.